# ENV vars for docker build in multi-stage build

Tags: docker

I have a multi-stage build where a python script runs in the first stage and uses several env vars.

How do I set these variables in the `docker build` command?

Here's the Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3 AS exporter

RUN mkdir -p /opt/export && pip install mysql-connector-python

ADD --chmod=555 export.py /opt/export


CMD ["python", "/opt/export/export.py"]

FROM nginx

COPY --from=exporter /tmp/gen/* /usr/share/nginx/html
```

My `export.py` script reads several env vars, and I have a `.env` file. If I run a container built with teh first stage and pass `--env-file` it works, but I can't seem to get it to work in the build stage.

How can I get the env vars to be available when building the first stage?

I don't care if they are saved in the image or not...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its seens you are looking for the `ARG` instruction. it's only avaible at the building time and won't be avaible at image runtime. Don’t use them for secrets which are not meant to stick around!

```
# default value if not using --build-arg instruction
ARG GLOBAL_AVAILABLE=iamglobal

FROM python:3 AS exporter

RUN mkdir -p /opt/export && pip install mysql-connector-python

ADD --chmod=555 export.py /opt/export

ARG GLOBAL_AVAILABLE
ENV GLOBAL_AVAILABLE=$GLOBAL_AVAILABLE

# only visible at exporter build stage:
ARG LOCAL_AVAILABLE=aimlocal

# multistage visible:
RUN echo ${GLOBAL_AVAILABLE}

# local stage visible (exporter build stage):
RUN echo ${LOCAL_AVAILABLE}

CMD ["python", "/opt/export/export.py"]

FROM nginx

COPY --from=exporter /tmp/gen/* /usr/share/nginx/html
```

you can pass custom `ARG` values by using the `--build-arg` flag:

`docker build -t <image-name>:<tag> --build-arg GLOBAL_AVAILABLE=abc .`

the general format to pass multiple args is:

`docker build -t <image-name>:<tag> --build-arg <key1>=<value1> --build-arg <key2>=<value2> .`

some refs:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/

https://blog.bitsrc.io/how-to-pass-environment-info-during-docker-builds-1f7c5566dd0e

https://vsupalov.com/docker-arg-env-variable-guide/